# Strict Regex Validation on an input string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a quick regex verification for an input string.

This is an example string format I am trying to achieve: `ABC=10:1;`

What I currently have: `var reg = new RegExp('(([AWT]\\w\\S=)?(\\d{0,9}:)?(\\d{0,9});)');`

With the above regex I am able to get the string, however all these strings are also getting accepted...

`ABC=`

`ABC=a:a;`

`ABC=#:#;`

What I need: `Three letter string = Any number(0-9) : Any number(0-9) ;`

**Unacceptable criteria** (like the examples above)

- Anything **non-numerical** after the `equals sign` and after the **colon** should be considered unacceptable.
- Anything after the **Semi-colon**.
- Anything before the **Three letter string**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

**Updates**

According to the answers below, `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\d+:\d+;$"` works perfectly fine, however when I test it with my code, it's invalid.

Here is the code:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\d+:\d+;$");
var x = $('td').find('input')[7].value;
console.log(x); // AWT=10:15;
        if (!x.match(reg)) {
            return [false, "Stop"];
            console.log("Invalid");
        } else {
            return [true, 'Success'];
            console.log("Valid");
       }
```

The above code always spits out **Invalid** even though I tested the regex.

I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: `10` in `ABC=10:1;` does not match "Any number(0-9)". Please clarify.

Comment: You should be able to use `^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\d:\d;$`. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your regexp could be simplified to this:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\d+:\d+;$"
```

Where:

- `^` and `$` - the beginning and the end of the line
- `[a-zA-Z]` - any characters from the range (latin characters in this case)
- `{3}` - exact number of the previous symbols (3 any latin characters in this case)
- `\d` - any digit
- `+` - repeat last symbol one or more times
- symbols `=:;` don't have to be escaped in this case

UPD:
If you need only one digit before the colon and one after the colon, then you shouldn't use `+` signs, just like in Cary Swoveland comment. But, according the example, there could be arbitrary length numbers here

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however when I test it in a regex generator, it gives me the right string. When I test it in my code, it says the string `AWT=10:12;` is invalid. I updated my question with the code.

Comment: You should escape "\" symbol in RegExp constructor: `var reg = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\\d+:\\d+;$");`.
Or, alternatively, you can use the literal notation: `var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\d+:\d+;$/;`